# Google script run at specific date (more than one date)

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help to write a script. Here's what I want to do: the script is time trigger (every day), but when it run, I want to add specific date (one date per rang(cells)). And if the date is not in the option, the script will run but do noting.

Here is the script that I have already work with the help from here:

```js
function AddProtectionToColumn() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = GetRange(ss);
  var protectSs = range.protect().setDescription('Protect');
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protectSs.addEditor(me);
  protectSs.removeEditors(protectSs.getEditors());
  if (protectSs.canDomainEdit()) {
    protectSs.setDomainEdit(false); 
  }
}

function GetRange(ss){
  var today = new Date().getDate();
  // assuming you're only making protected ranges on the first sheet
   var protections = ss.getSheets()[0].getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  if (at date == ('october 01, 2019')){ 
    return ss.getRange('A1:B5');

  if (at date == ('october 02, 2019')){ 
    return ss.getRange('C1:D5');
  }
}
```

The part of the script (protect) work well. I have trouble with the date setting thing. I try something and it didn't work. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: What is `at date`?

Comment: I try something with the getdate(), but I'm sure it's not correct. I'm not able the found how to use getdate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can use the `getDate()` method to get the number of the current date and use a conditional similar to your current code.*

#### Code example:

```js
function GetRange(ss){

  var today = new Date().getDate();
  var protections = ss.getSheets()[0].getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

  if (today == 1){ 
    return ss.getRange("day-1-range");
  }
  else if (today == 2){ 
    return ss.getRange("day-2-range");
  }
  else if (today == 3){
    return ss.getRange("day-3-range");
  }
  // else block continues...
  else if (today == 31){
    return ss.getRange("day-31-range");
  }
}
```

Honestly, I don't really recommend this as you're going to have a very large if block, but for your use case this will work.

#### Explanation:

The `getDate()` method returns a number, **which is equal to the numerical date of the day of the date object**.

For example:

```js
var date1 = new Date('01 October 2019').getDate(); // == 1
var date2 = new Date('21/12/1984').getDate(); // == 21
var date3 = new Date('Jan 14 2000').getDate(); // == 14
var date4 = new Date('29 February 2004').getDate(); // == 29
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly. Will this method allow me to associate a specific date for each range?

Comment: I think there's been some misunderstanding. This will allow you to use the `'october 01, 2019'` string as a date to compare. Your `GetRange()` funciton in your original question will not run on its own as the syntax is incorrect. If this answer isn't suitable, can you please share your sheet so I can understand your problem better and provide a more robust solution?

Comment: In the spreadsheet, each week there are 5 tables (1 for each day). This document will be shared with other people, so I need the tables to be protected automatically on a date. Each table must be associated with a date. I hope it's clearer! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lk-PgSHO0Ma2ZcA77TarRD4EnGgZDdBEsCNyjP8Lv9c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Okay I think I'm starting to understand! Does it change per day of the week or per date of the month? What needs to be different from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58168352/11551468)?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me, it's really appreciated!
The first answer you gave me works well if there is only 1 Monday, 1 Tuesday etc. 
However, I realized that the script is not really appropriate when I have several Mondays, Tuesdays etc. (I don't want every Monday, Tuesday etc. to be protected at the same time).  So, a date associated with a table (range) seems more appropriate. It change per date of the month. (one sheet per month). For example, someone will complete the first table on the x date and at the end of the day, this table will be protected. (trigger every day).

Comment: Ah okay! I understand. I have had a look at your sheet, where are you getting the date from? The tables only have the day of the week in them (lundi, mardi, etc).

Comment: You can replace Monday, Tuesday and so on with a date. The dates will be written manually.

Comment: You can do it similarly to my answer the other day. It'll make for a long if statement,  but I've updated my answer to show you.