# Google script run at a specific day (day of the year)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help with a script, I have already had help before on this platform with this script.
It's a protection script based on a day and different range.

At the moment : it per month (1-32 day)
Is it possible to set the day of the year (1-365) ? It will work better in my script.

[Here is the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186992/google-script-run-at-specific-date-more-than-one-date)

```
function AddProtectionToColumn() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var range = GetRange(ss);
      var protectSs = range.protect().setDescription('Protection automatique');
      var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
      protectSs.addEditor(me);
      protectSs.removeEditors(protectSs.getEditors());
      if (protectSs.canDomainEdit()) {
        protectSs.setDomainEdit(false); 
      }
    }

    function GetRange(ss){

  var today = new Date().getDate(); 
  var protections = ss.getSheets()[0].getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

  if (today == 289){ // day of the year
    return ss.getRange("J1:K4");
  }
  else if (today == 299){ 
    return ss.getRange("J5:K10");
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's possible to set a specific date and time - would that do?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. There will be several dates associated with a range. The range is the area that is automatically protected. There is a different range to protect every day. A time trigger is used (every day).

Comment: No worries "_At the moment : it per month (1-32 day) Is it possible to set the day of the year (1-365)_"  & "_There is a different range to protect every day._" It really seems as though the wording of your question is incomplete and ambiguous; may I suggest that you edit the question (and the title) to describe more accurately and fully the situation that you have, and the outcome that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Getting the day of the year**

`parseInt(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "D"));`

[Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

[Simple Date Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

So in your code:

```
function GetRange(ss){
  var today = parseInt(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "D"));
  var protections = ss.getSheets()[0].getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  if (today == 289){ // day of the year
    return ss.getRange("J1:K4");
  }
  else if (today == 299){ 
    return ss.getRange("J5:K10");
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand how to use this line. Does this allow me to have several dates (for each range)?

Comment: This is a way to get the day of the year for a given date.

Comment: In your code `var today=parseInt(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "D"));`